# Open Interface controller programmatically in WatchOS 2

Tags: swift, ios9, apple-watch, watchos-2

i have this scene that only show (please login from your iPhone)
and i check if i received user info from the counterpart iPhone application

the problem is when i use

```
presentControllerWithName("MyNoLoginInterface", context: nil)
```

it have a Cancel button to the main interface

is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use `setTitle:@""`

This is from appleDocumetation:

> Use the presentControllerWithName:context: and
>   presentControllerWithNames:contexts: methods to present your interface
>   controllers modally. **If the modal interface controller does not have a
>   title, its title is set to the string Cancel by default. You can set
>   the value of this string in your storyboard or change it at runtime
>   using the setTitle: method.** When the user taps the title string,
>   WatchKit automatically dismisses the modal interface without taking
>   any further actions.

[quote source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW22)

Comment: "The title of the modal interface is set to the string Cancel unless the presented interface controller explicitly changes it using the setTitle: method. Tapping the title dismisses the interface automatically. To dismiss the interface programmatically, call the dismissController method." so i can change the Cancel with an "Error" but still when clicked take my back to the application

Comment: set as title an empty string `@""`, it will still take you back, but at least the text is not there